# Change view on video end in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I get an error when trying to find the end time of the video

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentViewC: View {

    
    private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoToPlay", ofType: "mp4")!))
    
    // throw multiple errors
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

    func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        print("video finished")
        // how to change view here?
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: player)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear {
                    player.play()
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    player.pause()
                    player.seek(to: .zero)
                }
        }
        .background(Color(.black))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Once that is resolved, how do I change the view in the func playerDidFinishPlaying?

My app has this 'HomeView' which has three buttons, when clicked, they navigate to a new View which will play video. On Video end in the new view, I want to navigate back to this 'HomeView'

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let width: CGFloat = 400
        let height: CGFloat = 400
        
        let txtWidth: CGFloat = 300
        let txtHeight: CGFloat = 100
        
            
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image("app_bg3")
                    .resizable()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewC()) {
                        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                            Spacer()
                            
                            VStack  {
                                VStack {
                                    Image("OneCirclePlayBtn")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                        .frame(width: width, height: height)
                                    
                                    Text("The")
                                        .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Regular", size: 43))
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                                        .frame(width: txtWidth, height: txtHeight, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                    Text("Voice")
                                        .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Regular", size: 43))
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                                        .frame(width: txtWidth, height: txtHeight, alignment: .center)
                                        .offset(y: -50)
                                }
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }.offset(y: 100)
                HStack(spacing: 350) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewA()) {
                        VStack {
                            VStack {
                               Image("TwoCirclePlayBtn")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                                
                                Text("The Cast")
                                    .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Regular", size: 33))
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                                    .frame(width: txtWidth, height: txtHeight, alignment: .center)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewB()) {
                        VStack {
                            VStack {
                                Image("ThreeCirclePlayBtn")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: .center)



                                Text("The Artist")
                                    .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Regular", size: 33))
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                                    .frame(width: txtWidth, height: txtHeight, alignment: .center)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.offset(y: -150)
                }
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .accentColor(.white)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        .background(StatusBarHideHelperView())
    }
}


class StatusBarHideHelper: UIViewController {
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { true }    // << important !!
}

struct StatusBarHideHelperView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        StatusBarHideHelper()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class PlayerViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var videoDone = false
    
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Early Riser", ofType: "mp4")!))
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
            .sink { (_) in
                self.videoDone = true
                print("Video done")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.videoDone = false //reset it on the next run loop
                }
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

struct PlayerContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = PlayerViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: viewModel.player)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.player.play()
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    viewModel.player.pause()
                    viewModel.player.seek(to: .zero)
                }
            if viewModel.videoDone {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $viewModel.videoDone) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color(.black))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PlayerContentView()
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

I'm making the assumption here that you want to navigate using a `NavigationView`, but I can edit the answer if that's not the case.

What's going on here:

1. I moved the player and its 'done' state to an `ObservableObject` -- that way, I have a little more control of how I deal with the notification.
2. Upon receiving the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notification, I set `videoDone` to true
3. When `videoDone` is true, I render a `NavigationLink` in the view hierarchy, with `isActive` set to `videoDone`
4. Note that this will not work if your view isn't embedded in a `NavigationView` (see my `ContentView`) -- the `NavigationLink` won't do anything if it exists outside of that hierarchy.

**Update**:
In the event that you want to go *back* and not to a new View, the following would work, using `presentationMode` (same PlayerViewModel as before):

```
struct PlayerContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = PlayerViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: viewModel.player)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.player.play()
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    viewModel.player.pause()
                    viewModel.player.seek(to: .zero)
                }
        }
        .background(Color(.black))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onReceive(viewModel.$videoDone) { (videoDone) in
            if videoDone {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Cannot find type 'AnyCancellable' in scope` in the class. I currently have the class above my struct, should it be in a separate file?

Comment: import Combine at the top

Comment: Interesting bug, my 'HomeView' has buttons that when clicked, navigate to a new 'VideoView', which plays the video, then with your help, on video end, I navigate back to HomeView, but now HomeView has a back button, which it shouldn't. Any way to solve that?

Comment: I don't see any code referring to "HomeView" -- post code or an example and I can try to help.

Comment: Okay -- I assume you mean `ContentView` and not `HomeView` -- but, I see what you're saying now.  Instead of navigating to a *new* view, you want to navigate back to the original? I can edit my code to accommodate that.

Comment: I've updated with another example of how to navigate back instead of forward. I didn't try to edit your code because it's just too much for a small example, especially since there aren't all the views included so it would take a lot to recreate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228173/discussion-between-devlo-and-jnpdx).

Comment: New bug however, now, once back to ContentView, and if I click on the button again to play the video again, it navigates to the video view, then immediately back to ContentView, as if the videoDone is always now set to true.

I tried setting it back to false in the .onReceive {
`if videoDone {
viewModel.videoDone = false
}`
but that does not do the trick

Answer (score 3):

- I updated the answer completely after the explanation in the comment

Your view should be like this;

```
struct PlayerContentView: View {

@State var isVideoPlayed = false
let playerDidFinishNotification = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)

private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoToPlay", ofType: "mp4")!))

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: player)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                player.pause()
                player.seek(to: .zero)
            }
    }
    .background(Color(.black))
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .onReceive(playerDidFinishNotification, perform: { _ in
        isVideoPlayed = true
        NavigationLink("Content View", destination: ContentView(), isActive: $isVideoPlayed)
    })
 }
}
```

Instead of **navigation link**, you can also use, **present** or **sheet**

p.s. you should replace **PlayerContentView** with **ContentViewC**

Comment: I'm not trying to hide a view, rather, I'm trying to navigate to a new screen after the video ends.

Comment: so you can navigate to another screen by "NavigationLink" . you can add a navigationLink where "how to change view here?" is written.

Comment: `func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) { isViewHidden = true NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) }` throws a new error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call, but ContentView does not take any parameters, so not sure why that error is.

Comment: @musakokcen I've a slightly different question, if I wanted it so that if the current video time is X ie 10 seconds, then to pause the video, how would I do this? If you wouldn't mind responding then I could open up a new question with this? Cheers,

Comment: I think that you can define completion and define it in "AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: player)", then you can call the completion @Aiyush
I hope it helps.

Comment: this is the way